# MySQL GROUP BY function takes much time

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, group-by

I have been saerching for some data using the following query.I am a newby.please pardon if any design error.

```
SELECT
    j.applicant_uid,
    j.job_id,u.id,
    MAX(u.name),
    ui.phone,
    ui.fullname,
    ui.img,
    ui.address,
    u.r_date,
    r.sex,
    r.present_salary,
    w.working,
    w.description,
    e.institute_name,
    e.exam_name,
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(w.time_start, w.time_end) / 365.25) AS experience,
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),r.dob) / 365.25) AS age,
    r. preferred_district,
    e.major_group ,
    w.compnay_name,
    w.designation,
    j.ukey
FROM job_apply as j               
INNER JOIN users u            ON j.applicant_uid = u.id
INNER JOIN resume r           ON j.applicant_uid = r.uid
INNER JOIN work_history w     ON j.applicant_uid = w.uid 
INNER JOIN education e        ON j.applicant_uid = e.uid
INNER JOIN user_other_info ui ON j.applicant_uid = ui.uid
WHERE `j.job_id`='131'
  AND `r.sex`                 LIKE '%1%'
  AND  `r.preferred_district` LIKE '%14%'
  AND `w.description`         LIKE '%brac%'
   OR `e.exam_name`           LIKE '%brac%'
   OR `w.compnay_name`        LIKE '%brac%'
   OR `w.designation`         LIKE '%brac%'
   OR `e.institute_name`      LIKE '%brac%'
GROUP BY `u.id`
HAVING `experience` >= '1'
  AND `r.present_salary` BETWEEN '15000' AND '20000'
```

But it takes around 30.017 sec.How to reduce the query time??What could be the reason??I have added the alias.

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    `role_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_type` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `umail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `block` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `r_date` date NOT NULL,
    `u_date` date NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4560 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the resume table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `resume` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `career_objective` varchar(5000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `father` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `mother` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `dob` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `birth_place` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `nationality` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `sex` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `looking_for` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `present_salary` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `expected_salary` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `preferred_category` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `preferred_district` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `declaration` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `facebook_link` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `linkedin_link` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1905 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and the following is:

```
    CREATE TABLE `education` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `institute_name` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `exam_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `major_group` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `result` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `passing_year` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5279 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the job_apply table.please do consider db design mistakes:

```
    CREATE TABLE `job_apply` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `applicant_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ukey` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `is_short_list` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_rejected` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `note` varchar(5000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `cv_viewed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ssc_certificate` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `ssc_marksheet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `hsc_certificate` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `hsc_marksheet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `graduation_certificate` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `graduation_marksheet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `experience_certificate` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `recommendation_letter` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `ans` varchar(5000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2079 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please add table aliases for all columns in the query, so we can see where they come from.

Comment: Note that (at least) your WHERE clause seems to be wrong. You probably need parentheses around the `OR` conditions. That might already improve the performance alot.

Comment: why are you grouping by `u.id`?  Which joins can create multiple "copies" of the user?  Why do you have a filter in the `HAVING` clause, it looks like it should be in the `WHERE` clause?  Your `WHERE` clause has no brackets, and is essentially doing `(a AND b AND c) OR (d) OR (e)`, which surely can't be right?  Why are you doing `LIKE '%xxxx%'` all over the place *(each one of those is a VERY expensive operation, as no indexes can be used)*?  Why is `present_salary` a VARCHAR!?  You can get really wierd results because of that.

Comment: You asked where the brackets should be, then deleted the question, but here's the answer : `a AND b AND c AND (x OR y OR z)`

Comment: using experience in where condition was causing error and group by used as distinct did not work.

Comment: And you need (at least) indexes on `uid` for every table. However - I vote to close this question as `too broad`, because it doesn't look like this query can return a meaningfull result. Optimizing a query that doesn't return correct results doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` solution is a fudge.  It's a bad idea for a lot of reasons.  Explain the problems you had that lead to the use of `GROUP BY` and we'll be able to offer better solutions.

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie your every point helped me finding out the error i have been doing.

Comment: how should i use indexing on uid??

Comment: To add an index: `ALTER TABLE resume ADD INDEX (uid);`. When the index is created MySQL will use it for your joins.

Comment: should I add this indexing for each table associated??

Comment: There's no need to guess about why a query is slow. Consult the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html documentation my answer mentions. The plan will reveal steps where a large number of rows are accessed, much larger than you feel is necessary. Each such step in the plan is an opportunity to offer the optimizer a better access path, such as an index, then go through an edit-run-debug cycle where you review the revised plan and decide if it is good enough yet. The current plan is far from efficient.

Comment: Good grief!  What Universe are you living in?  `sex VARCHAR(50)` and `AND r.sex LIKE '%1%'` !  Most datasets have only 2, maybe 3 flavors of sex.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here, but one leaps off the page: your use of wildcard patterns like '%brac%'. Please understand that 'brac%' can exploit an index, but a wildcard with leading percent-sign cannot. You are forcing a tablescan. Several, it seems.

You made present_salary varchar(100), rather than numeric, which seems an extremely poor design choice. It would lead to trouble if you asked for rows `BETWEEN '9000' and '11000'`, as lexicographic order differs from numeric order.

Please edit your question to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE job_apply`, also users, resume, work_history, education, and user_other_info. Describe approximate table sizes, perhaps they are so many thousands of rows. And most importantly, do include [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html) output so we see the plan the backend optimizer settled on.

You're joining on uid in several places, yet you chose not to offer the optimizer an index on any of them, so it is forced to tablescan. You did not include EXPLAIN output, but from the schema it is clear that you cannot exploit selectivity, and will have to scan all tables.

Thank you for the added formatting, that's quite helpful.

Typo: w.compnay_name

You have a bunch of latin1 tables, which is fine, though you might prefer to settle on a default of utf8 tables. What is troubling is your mixed use of latin1 and utf8 varchars. Much better to settle on one, e.g. utf8. You're joining strictly on integer uids, but if you ever were to equijoin on text columns you would need same collation and same charset in order to exploit indexes properly.

Answer (score 0):

I call this the "explode-implode syndrone".  The query `JOINs` lots of tables, thereby exploding the number of rows being looked at, then it implodes the mess with a `GROUP BY`.

The usual cure is to think of it is two steps.  First, find the `u.id` values that match the various `WHERE` clauses.  Since you have data scattered across various tables, this will still be costly.  However, you won't be hauling around the dozens of other columns only to throw away much info later.

The second step is to `JOIN` (again, if necessary) to the various tables to get the other columns needed.

Suggest you focus on the performance of step 1 since step two will be cheap (though verbose).

Other problems:

- Leading wildcard (`%`) in `LIKE` prohibits use of indexes.  Look into `FULLTEXT` for columns that are composed of text.
- Don't look for numbers with `LIKE` (such as `sex LIKE '%1%'`).
- OR is not good for performance, especially when spread across multiple tables.
- Is there a good reason for having the data in more than one (maybe two) tables?  Some performance problems decrease when looking at a single table.

There are other issues, but these tips may help move you forward.